# React elements are not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The page consists of two input fields one is labeled as username and the other one is labeled as Age,  followed by a button. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, the page is just blank.

[![Current Output][1]][1]

[![Expected Output][2]][2]

Node Version: 15.3.0
Npm: 8.3.0

Adduser.js:

```
import Card from '../UI/Cards';
import classes from './AddUser.module.css'
import Button from '../UI/Button';

function AddUser() {
const [entereUsername, setEnteredUsername] = usestate('');
const [enteredAge, setEnteredAge] = useState('');

  const addUserHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const usernameChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredUsername(event.target.value)
    console.log(entereUsername, enteredAge)
  }

  const ageChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredAge(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <Card className={classes.input}>
      <form onSubmit={addUserHandler}>
        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
        <input id="username" type="text" onChange={usernameChangeHandler}/>
        <label htmlFor="age">Age (Years)</label>
        <input id="age" type="number" onChange={ageChangeHandler}/>
        <Button type="submit">Add User</Button>
      </form>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default AddUser;
```

Button.js

```
function Button(props) {
  return (
    <button
      className={classes.button}
      type={props.type || "button"}
      onClick={props.onClick}
    >
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

Console :

````
AddUser.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Object is not a function or its return value is not iterable
    at AddUser (AddUser.js:7:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16141:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20838:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22342:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4157:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4206:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4270:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27243:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26392:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26303:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26271:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25577:1)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:239:1)
    at performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:533:1)
    at run (setImmediate.js:40:1)
    at runIfPresent (setImmediate.js:69:1)
    at onGlobalMessage (setImmediate.js:109:1) ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPVCy.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGYTX.png
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code in your `Button` component.

Error seems to be thrown because you don't pass `onClick` as `props` when you use `Button` component.

```
function Button(props) {
  return (
    <button
      {...props}
      className={classes.button}
      type={props.type || "button"}
    >
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

You have a typo here: `const [entereUsername, setEnteredUsername] = usestate('');` `usestate` --> `useState`

Change it by following:

```
const [entereUsername, setEnteredUsername] = useState('');
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't work

Comment: You have a typo in your code. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adduser.js

```
import Card from '../UI/Cards';
import classes from './AddUser.module.css'
import Button from '../UI/Button';

function AddUser() {
const [entereUsername, setEnteredUsername] = useState('');
const [enteredAge, setEnteredAge] = useState('');

  const addUserHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const usernameChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredUsername(event.target.value)
    console.log(entereUsername, enteredAge)
  }

  const ageChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredAge(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <Card className={classes.input}>
      <form onSubmit={addUserHandler}>
        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
        <input id="username" type="text" onChange={usernameChangeHandler}/>
        <label htmlFor="age">Age (Years)</label>
        <input id="age" type="number" onChange={ageChangeHandler}/>
        <Button type="submit">Add User</Button>
      </form>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default AddUser;
```

Button.js

```
function Button(props) {
  return (
    <button
      {...props}
      className={classes.button}
      type={props.type || "button"}
    >
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
}

export default Button;
```